# Does preloading order in <head> matter?

Tags: html, preloading

I'm using preloading for a heavy image that causes CLS on my website when it's not preloaded which is what is recommended.

But on throttled slow connectivity, the preloading takes too much time, in a manner that the image still comes in late and causes CLS.

It's a big website with a lot of ressources being loaded in the head aswell as opengraph etc. so my question is the following : is there any point in bringing the preloading tags (image, stylesheets) right up to the top of the head, will that speed-up the preloading at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Preloading isn't the solution you want for CLS fixes.  For CLS you should look at adding image height/width, or at least aspect-ratio css to it so the space is reserved for it.

Preload tags will start loading in the order they are in the head, they may get reprioritised by the browser based on their type (fonts vs scripts vs css have slightly different initial priorities) or when the browser actually tries using it, but generally only if you're on http2+.

Preload http headers appear to be slightly faster than preload tags.